# Rails mail render empty mail body in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mail-gem

I use rails Rails 3.2.3 and Resque to send an emails.
For some strange reason emails on production sended with empty body.
I try reproduce problem localy but with no luck.
production log does not have anything strange

```
Sent mail to somemail@rambler.ru (730ms)
  Rendered user_mailer/_activation_email.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered user_mailer/activate_service_provider_with_email.html.erb within  layouts/user_mailer (83.2ms)

Sent mail to somemail@rambler.ru (737ms)
  Rendered user_mailer/_activation_email.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered user_mailer/activate_service_provider_with_email.html.erb within   layouts/user_mailer (83.3ms)

Sent mail to somemail@rambler.ru (740ms)
  Rendered user_mailer/discount.html.erb within layouts/user_mailer (231.6ms)

Sent mail to somemail@rambler.ru (536ms)
Starting the New Relic Agent.
Installed New Relic Browser Monitoring middleware
Creating scope :near. Overwriting existing method ServiceProvider.near.
Connected to NewRelic Service at collector-2.newrelic.com
```

Can anybody suggest what should I check - cache e.t.c to find problem ...
Email should contain html inside but I get plain text content type
**Here is mail text:**

```
Delivered-To: somemail@gmail.com
Received: by 11.11.66.777 with SMTP id c8csp32365iei;
    Fri, 6 Jul 2012 06:34:44 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 11.22.333.444 with SMTP id lv8mr2489460igc.41.1341581684021;
    Fri, 06 Jul 2012 06:34:44 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <noreply@oursite.ua>
Received: from soursite.ru (oursite.ru. [184.106.242.18])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id vb2si4216338igc.71.2012.07.06.06.34.43
    (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
    Fri, 06 Jul 2012 06:34:44 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of noreply@oursite.ua designates 111.11.111.11   as permitted sender) client-ip=123.456.78.90;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of  noreply@oursite.ua   designates 123.456.78.908 as permitted sender)  smtp.mail=noreply@oursite.ua
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1] helo=localhost.localdomain)
by oursite.ru with esmtp (Exim 4.71)
(envelope-from <noreply@oursite.ua>)
id 1Sn8k3-00086o-Vt
for somemail@gmail.com; Fri, 06 Jul 2012 13:38:40 +0000
Date: Fri, 06 Jul 2012 13:38:39 +0000
From: noreply@oursite.ua
To: somemail@gmail.com
Message-ID: <4ff6ea5fb7942_79c0f9c45069741@OURSITE.ru.mail>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?=D0=9C=D1=8B?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=B8=D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B8=D0=BC_=D0=BA?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_=D0=92=D0=B0=D0=BC?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_=D0=BA=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=B5=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B2_=D0=B8?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_=D0=BE=D0=BF=D0=BB=D0=B0=D1=87=D0=B8=D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=B5=D0=BC?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_=D0=B8=D0=BC_=D1=83=D1=81=D0=BB=D1=83=D0=B3=D0=B8?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_=D0=92=D0=B0=D1=88=D0=B5=D0=B3=D0=BE?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_=D1=81=D0=B0=D0=BB=D0=BE=D0=BD=D0=B0:?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_=D0=9F=D0=B0=D1=80=D1=82=D0=BD=D0=B5=D1=80=D1=81=D0=BA=D0=B0=D1=8F?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B3=D1=80=D0=B0=D0=BC=D0=BC=D0=B0?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_=D0=BE=D1=82?=
 =?UTF- ?Q?_=D0=98=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=BD=D0=B5=D1=82-=D0=BF=D0=BE=D1=80=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BB=      D0=B0?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?=
 Mime-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

**And here is correct mail which I get on development**

```
Return-Path: <noreply@oursite.ua>
Received: from [11.2.2.21] (HELO mx21.rambler.ru)
  by mail43.rambler.ru (rmaild SMTP 1.3.41)
  with ESMTP id 44865232 for someguy@rambler.ru; Fri, 06 Jul 2012 17:24:06 +0400
Received: from oursite.ru (oursite.ru [111.456.111.11])
    by mx21.rambler.ru (Postfix) with ESMTP id E6D5ED85F69
    for <someguy@rambler.ru>; Fri,  6 Jul 2012 17:24:05 +0400 (MSK)
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1] helo=localhost.localdomain)
    by oursite.ru with esmtp (Exim 4.71)
    (envelope-from <noreply@oursite.ua>)
    id 1Sn8Zl-0007up-Cj
    for someguy@rambler.ru; Fri, 06 Jul 2012 13:28:01 +0000
Date: Fri, 06 Jul 2012 13:28:01 +0000
From: noreply@oursite.ua
To: someguy@rambler.ru
Message-ID: <4ff6e7e127236_76d3127debc36876@oursite.ru.mail>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?=D0=90=D0=BA=D1=82=D0=B8=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=86=D0=B8=D1=8F?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_=D0=B0=D0=BA=D0=BA=D0=B0=D1=83=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B0_=D0=B2_oursite?=
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.o=
rg/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang=3D"en-GB">
<head>
    <title>oursite email notification</title>
    <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"application/xhtml+xml; char=
set=3Dutf-8" />
    <meta name=3D"description" content=3D"oursite!" />
    <meta name=3D"keywords" content=3D"" />
    <meta name=3D"robots" content=3D"index, follow" />
    <meta http-equiv=3D"X-UA-Compatible" content=3D"IE=3Dedge" /> <!-- IE=
 9 rounded corners -->
</head>
<body>
 =

    <div style=3D"border:4px solid #a90e15; width:600px; padding:20px; ba=
ckground-color:#fff; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
        <div style=3D"color:#a90e15; font-size:60px; letter-spacing:-1px;=
 font-weight:lighter;">Style <span style=3D"background-color:#a90e15; col=
or:#fff; font-size: 40px; padding:10px; font-weight:bold;">Up</span></div=
><br />
        <div style=3D"color:#000; font-size:14px;">
            =

                            =D0=94=D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=80=D0=BE =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=B6=D0=B0=
=D0=BB=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=B2 oursite, DeleteThis!<br />
          =D0=94=D0=BB=D1=8F =D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B3=D0=BE =D1=87=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=
=B1=D1=8B =D0=B0=D0=BA=D1=82=D0=B8=D0=B2=D0=B8=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=
=82=D1=8C =D0=92=D0=B0=D1=88 =D0=B0=D0=BA=D0=BA=D0=B0=D1=83=D0=BD=D1=82 =D0=
=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B9=D0=B4=D0=B8=D1=82=D0=B5 =D0=BF=D0=BE =D1=81=D1=81=D1=
=8B=D0=BB=D0=BA=D0=B5 <a href=3D"http://kiev.oursite.ua/activate/S6oqGyan=
66i83NoTNUI">http://kiev.oursite.ua/activate/S6oqGyan66i83NoTNUI</a>.<br =
/>

          <br />
          <br />

            =

</div>

    </div><!-- end of accom div -->

    <div style=3D"color:#000; background-color:#FBF5E5; font-size:12px; w=
idth:628px; padding:10px; text-align:center; font-family:Helvetica, Arial=
, sans-serif;">
        =D0=93=D1=80=D1=83=D0=BF=D0=BF=D0=B0 oursite! <a href=3D"http://v=
kontakte.ru/club1111409799" style=3D"color:#000; font-weight:bold;">=D0=B2=D0=
=BA=D0=BE=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BA=D1=82=D0=B5</a><br />
        =D0=93=D1=80=D1=83=D0=BF=D0=BF=D0=B0 =D0=B2 <a href=3D"http://www=
.facebook.com/oursite.ru" style=3D"color:#000; font-weight:bold;">faceboo=
k</a><br />
        =D0=9D=D0=B0=D1=88=D0=B8 =D0=BD=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=BE=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B8=
 =D0=B2 <a href=3D"https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=3Doursite_=
ru" style=3D"color:#000; font-weight:bold;">twitter</a><br />
        <a href=3D"oursite.ua" style=3D"color:#000; font-weight:bold;"></=
a><br /><br />
        &copy; 2011 oursite! =

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are these multipart emails by any chance?

Comment: it should send html content but in it. But I save one of them to disk and open with editor - and find Content-Type: text/plain;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I find solution.
HTML template for mail contain only **<%= render 'some_partial' %>**
and nothing else
when I copy text from partial to template it begin render correctly.